# ruby eval metaprogramming trick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, eval

I'm trying to find a way to evaluate an expression that consists of a function and argument. The problem is, I don't want the argument converted into a string.

Specifically, I have the function x="display_datetime" of type String, which takes an object y of type Time. The function name is created dynamically, so I can't just type, display_datetime(y).

What I've tried:

- **eval("#{x}(#{y})")** - This is how I'd normally do it, but this converts the Time to a string. The whole purpose of "display_datetime" is to do a custom Time to string conversion, so this would not be useful
- **x.send(y)** - This does not compile, because send is meant to send classes functions, not functions arguments.
- **x.constantize**... - also doesn't compile, even if x includes the classname.
- **y.send(:to_s(:datetime))** This approach is less than ideal, but I still can't get it to work. display_datetime just calls y.to_s(:datetime), so I tried setting the dynamically generated function name x to simply be .to_s(:datetime), then invoking x on y with the send command. This would work, except for the fact that to_s takes an argument. I don't know how to call send (or try) when the argument being sent has to take an argument
- Another idea I've had is to override the Time class to add a conversion function to it like to_s, but that doesn't take any argument.

Those last two approaches are less than ideal. I feel like there has to be some better way of doing this along the lines of the first 3 approaches.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: under which namespace did you create your `display_datetime`

Comment: Under ApplicationHelper

Comment: Sorry for not responding to posts. This somehow fell off the radar. I will respond now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with `send`. Do this:

```
send(x, y)
```

Comment: This works. You just need to call send on the object. So I'm accepting this answer. I didn't know send could take a function name and an argument list. I verified that if y is of type fixnum, the type is still fix num inside the function. So there's no string conversion taking place. This makes this the best approach for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
s = "display_datetime" # function name, dynamic
y = Time.now           # or some other Time object
```

And some object `o` that responds to the `display_datetime()` method, you can call `o.display_datetime` dynamically in several ways, at least:

```
o.send(s.intern, y)    # => o.send(:display_datetime, y)
```

Or,

```
eval("o.#{s}(y)")      # => eval("o.display_datetime(y)")
```

Alternatively,

```
o.instance_eval("#{s}(y)") # => o.instance_eval("display_datetime(y)")
```

Or if you want evalception, if the variable `n` contains the name of the variable `o`:

```
n = 'o'
eval %Q(#{n}.send(:instance_eval, "\#{s}(y)"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your first solution works well for me. The last 3 don't work, because y gets stringified in all those. I gave the answer to the other guy though, because his came in earlier.